# Google Cloud Translate API : challenge setup (R and/or Python)

Tags: r, python-3.x, google-translate

I understand from previous questions that access to Google Translate API may have recently changed.
My goal is to translate individual tweets in a dataframe from X Language to English.
I tried to setup the Google Cloud Translate API with no success
I have setup gcloud sdk, enabled the billing and looks like the certification is ok. But, still no success.
Has anyone else had any recent experience with it using R and/or Python?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, for anyone seeking to translate dataframes/variables

translateR doesnt seem to accept the Google API key

However, everything works very smoothly using the "googleLangaugeR" package